# I wanna change type of programming languages of designated rows String into int

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I wanna change type of programming languages of designated rows String into int.
Now,I am making data analysis app by using numpy&scipy&pandas&etc.
My app read csv files.I wanna designate int type against rows which are lines only 10~15 (other all rows are string type).
When I wrote code like

```
x = pandas.pd.read_csv('filename/csv file',header=1,parse_data=True,converters={9:14,lambda x:x.decode('int')})
```

Syntax error happen(`:expected error`) .I think my code is wrong.But I do not know how to fix it.What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible, but not recommended, because get mixed `types` `int` with `str` and some pandas functions fail.

Select rows by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) if need select by index values or by position by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and then convert to `int`:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,5)), columns=list('ABCDE')).astype(str)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  8  8  3  7  7
1  0  4  2  5  2
2  2  2  1  0  8
3  4  0  9  6  2
4  4  1  5  3  4
5  4  3  7  1  1
6  7  7  0  2  9
7  9  3  2  5  8
8  1  0  7  6  2
9  0  8  2  5  1

df.loc[3:8] = df.loc[3:8].astype(int)

print (type(df.loc[0, 'A']))
<class 'str'>

print (type(df.loc[4, 'A']))
<class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

`converters={9:14,lambda x:x.decode('int')})` is no valid python syntax.

However, you cannot change the data type per row. Only per column as in pandas, each column has a data type, not each cell or row.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `converters`, it's neither a `dict` nor a `set`.